# What is the most accurate joda-time representation for "DateUTC"?

Tags: java, date, datetime, jodatime, utc

Up until now we have been using joda-time class `DateTime` to represent date-time data with `UTC` timezone, and this meets our requirements nicely.

Example: `2014-11-07T14:10:00Z`

Now, we have a requirement to represent "date" data (in UTC timezone).

Example: `2014-11-07`

There exists a `LocalDate` joda-time class, and a method to convert from `DateTime` via `DateTime.toLocalDate()`.

I looked for a joda-time class which I thought would exist `DateUTC` - but it doesn't seem to exist!

Can someone please point me in the right direction, or in fact specify what is the best joda-time class for representing "date-UTC" data (without timestamp) ?

P.s. we are not ready to move to java 8 yet, since we have a lot of code using joda-time library

Comment: Since your `DateTime` is in UTC already, you should be fine with `LocalDate`. If you just need a string representation, `LocalData#toString()` should serve you well http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toString() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DateTime` object is in UTC, converting it to `LocalDate` is fine if you don't care about time. If it's not already in UTC, you can convert it to UTC using `DateTime.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).toLocalDate()`

`LocalDate` represents only the date components, without timezone information. Therefore, your code can just use it and assume it's in UTC, as long as you're consistent. For a string representation, you can use `LocalDate.toString()`.

However, if all you want is to format your existing `DateTime` object so that the string representation only shows the date components, then you shouldn't need to use `LocalDate`. Just format it to only show the dates: `DateTime.toString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.